# docker container exist but does not run with container ID

Tags: docker

I have created a container locally. Then, I run the following command:

```
docker ps -a
```

output is:

```
ONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND      CREATED        STATUS                        PORTS     NAMES
abc6f4d50931   airflow   "/bin/zsh"   17 hours ago   Exited (137) 21 minutes ago             xenodochial_mclaren
```

Then I try to run the container with the following command, it create a new container with same IMAGE but different container ID instead opening the container with this image name which exist.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -it airflow /bin/zsh/
```

The output of docker images command is:

```
REPOSITORY               TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
airflow                  airflow   63e2e36735a6   46 hours ago   704MB
airflow                  latest    63e2e36735a6   46 hours ago   704MB
docker/getting-started   latest    083d7564d904   6 weeks ago    28MB
```

Why is this creating new containers?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden Thanks. There may be something i am missing but the problem is clear. I have a container ID abc6f4d50931 that I wish to run.

Comment: The weird thing is I can start it from VS Code but I would like to use command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `docker run ...` you spin out a new cointainer from the image.

The status of your container is `Exited` as you can check from the `docker ps -a` output.

If you want to start again the same container, you can try `docker start abc6f4d50931`.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to map ports by stopping the container and using docker run command again but it seems impossible. So I have to create a new container with mapped ports. The problem is all the content of the previous container will be gone...

Comment: That is true, once you create a container, you are not able to change ports expure of that container. You need to create a new one.